# How to keep virtualenv always on in production?

Tags: virtualenv, production-environment

I use virtualenv to maintain environments for projects locally. I also use virtualenvwrapper, so I can switch between environments using

```
workon project1
```

However, when using virtualenv, you need your virtual environment to be active. I've just installed virtualenv on an ec2 instance, but how can I make sure the environment stays active? My best attempt at doing this right now is just putting the proper virtualenv commands in .bashrc. However, I'm exactly sure how this part all works... if the server restarts, will the  .bashrc be run?

Essentially, what is the best way to keep a virtualenv always on on a production server?

Answer (score 4):

"Activating a virtualenv" basically means you are changing your `$PATH` environment variable.

If you want to *always* have a virtualenv activated, prepend your virtualenv `bin` path to `$PATH` environment variable somewhere that gets executed before your commands run (`~/.bashrc` is an option).

Example (using `~/.bashrc`):

```
export PATH=/path/to/myenv/bin:$PATH
```

(Assuming `/path/to/myenv` is where my virtualenv is placed)

`~/.bashrc` is only executed when you start a new bash shell (even after restarts). If you never start a bash shell, `~/.bashrc` never gets executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That mostly answers it... but the problem is that .bashrc doesnt always get executed... for example in a non-interactive shell (I modified to fix this)... but then on certain incoming http requests I wasnt sure how to keep the virtual env "on" for the apache server

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `virtualenv` to be really permanent to your project, you could stuff the following two lines directly into your code:

```
activate_this = 'this_is_my_project/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```